# Is there any way to find the current controller name inside model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

User model can be updated using Registration controller and Password controller. Is there any way to find from which controller update method is called inside model.?

I want to find the controller name inside model. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between both? Can you please post some code that shows the difference between both updated? There might be a better way to handle this.

Comment: I have some validation for phone (presence true), There is a option to invite user in that case user created without phone number. But when user try to reset his password (forgot password) i am getting error "phone can't be blank". That's why i want to skip validation only when request come from password controller.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect example why it might be a good idea to move validations from the models into service objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Model and Controller layers are separated. Model is not aware of any controller-related stuff.

The only way to get the controller's name in the model is to pass the name of the controller as an argument to some method defined in model.

I never saw a real use of knowing the controller's name in model. Such need IMHO means you designed things wrong.

Comment: I have some validation for phone (presence true), There is a option to invite user in that case user created without phone number. But when user try to reset his password (forgot password) i am getting error "phone can't be blank". That's why i want to skip validation only when request come from password controller.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose an invited user is not activated yet. So how about defining your presence validation only on active users? Maybe by adding something like this:

```
validates_presence_of :phone_number, if :activated?
```

I haven't tested the code, so it's not copy-safe ;)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    with_options :if => :phone_required do |user|
        user.validates_presence_of :phone
    end
end
```

`phone_required` is database column so you need to create migration for user.

In your controller you need to set

```
your_user.phone_required = false
```

or

```
your_user.phone_required = true
```

before saving.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly discourage this practice as a model should be oblivious of controllers but it's not hard to accomplish if you use virtual attributes in your model

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr :controller
end
```

Now.. you can just pass in the controller when you update, such as:

```
class SomeModelsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @some_model.update_attributes(params[:some_model].merge(controller: self))
  end
end
```